# angularjs push empty element to array

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add new rows.cell element but push syntax is not clear for me.
If i specify push([]) i see on page changes. However instead of new empty div created i see new  with square brackets "[]".

Pleas advise how to add new empty element to each rows.cell array?

**html code:**

```
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <div class="cell" ng-repeat="cell in row.cell">{{ cell }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**controller code:**

```
     angular.module("myapp", [])
     .controller("infoTable", function($scope) {
        $scope.rows = [
                       {"id": 10, "cell": ['a','b','c']}, 
                       {"id": 11, "cell": ['a','b','c']}
                      ];
        $scope.addColumn = function (){
            $scope.rows.forEach(function($row){
                $row.cell.push([]);
            });
        }
     });
```

**Solved:**
"track by $index" added to ng-repeat="cell in row.cell"
And now new array element can be added using

```
$row.cell.push('');
```

Comment: try 
var cell={}; $row.cell.push(cell );

Comment: @Anita i tried. in such case i see "{}" inside div

Comment: if you want then you can put condition like this : '<div class="cell" ng-repeat="cell in row.cell">
<span ng-show="cell !== undefined  && cell !== null ">{{ cell }}</span></div>' That may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to add `'d'` to each array it would be

```
$scope.rows.forEach(function($row){
   $row.cell.push('d');
});

//{"id": 10, "cell": ['a','b','c','d']}
```

Comment: It work once, then error occurs ngRepeat:dupes. Anyhow i need to add empty element.

Comment: Well you would need to change the value each time or use `track by $index` in your `ng-repeat`. Not really sure what you are trying to do exactly

Comment: i want to change row.cell array after each addColumn trigger. to have {"id": 10, "cell": ['a','b','c','','','','']}

Comment: WHat I mean is I don't know how you are setting values. Try using `track by`

Comment: This code will add 'd' element to cell. Show in ng-repeat it will show 'd' in the div.. How this will create empty div?  Your question was to create empty div. Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing an array to the array. I'm not positive, but I think you're looking to push a document to the array. Try

```
$row.cell.push({});
```

Comment: in such case new array element value equal '{}'